# Binance API create futures order with take profit limit and stop loss market

Tags: binance, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

I would like to send via the Binance API three futures orders simultaneously. The first one is a simple, initial opening order. The second and the third are corresponding take profit and stop loss orders as outlined below. Now my question: I would like to modify the second order to a take profit limit order. This should somehow be possible according to the Binance API/client documentation.

```py
SELL order

buy_limit = client.futures_create_order(
symbol=coin,
side='BUY',
positionSide='LONG',
type='MARKET',
quantity=0.001
)

tp = round(45000,2) # TakeProfit = 45000

sl = round(50000,2) # StopLoss = 50000

TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET order

sell_gain_market = client.futures_create_order(
symbol=coin,
side='SELL',
positionSide='LONG',
type='TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET',
stopPrice=tp,
closePosition=True,
timeInForce='GTE_GTC',
workingType='MARK_PRICE',
priceProtect=True
)

STOP_MARKET order

sell_stop_market = client.futures_create_order(
symbol=coin,
side='SELL',
positionSide='LONG',
type='STOP_MARKET',
stopPrice=sl,
closePosition=True,
timeInForce='GTE_GTC',
workingType='MARK_PRICE',
priceProtect=True
)
```

Binance client:
https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/master/binance/client.py

I already tried to modify the type, workingType and priceProtect parameters but was not able to find a solution. Obviously it is important that the properties if the initial order is getting closed through either the take profit or stop loss order, the other not filled order gets canceled.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things that need adjustment based on the official Binance API documentation.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve the desired functionality:

```py
# Initial BUY MARKET order
buy_limit = client.futures_create_order(
    symbol=coin,
    side='BUY',
    positionSide='LONG',
    type='MARKET',
    quantity=0.001
)

tp = round(45000, 2)  # TakeProfit = 45000
sl = round(50000, 2)  # StopLoss = 50000

# TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT order (modify this)
take_profit_limit = client.futures_create_order(
    symbol=coin,
    side='SELL',
    positionSide='LONG',
    type='TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT',
    timeInForce='GTC',  # GTC (Good 'Til Canceled)
    quantity=0.001,
    price=tp,           # Specify the take profit price
    stopPrice=tp,       # Specify the trigger price
    closePosition=True
)

# STOP_MARKET order
stop_market = client.futures_create_order(
    symbol=coin,
    side='SELL',
    positionSide='LONG',
    type='STOP_MARKET',
    quantity=0.001,
    stopPrice=sl,       # Specify the trigger price
    closePosition=True
)
```

The key modification is for the take profit order. You should use the `TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT` order type for a take profit limit order. The `price` parameter specifies the price at which you want to execute the take profit order, and the `stopPrice` parameter specifies the trigger price. The `timeInForce` should be set to 'GTC' (Good 'Til Canceled) for the take profit limit order.

Please ensure you have the correct values for `coin`, and review the Binance Futures API documentation for any updates or additional parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately if I use the above code I still get an error message APIError(code=-1116): Invalid orderType.

Comment: Or maybe replace `'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'` with `'TAKE_PROFIT'` and see if that resolves the issue. I apologize if I caused any confusion or inconvenience.